# Convergence of Series in Hilbert Spaces

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, inner-products

Let $\{e_j\}_{j\in\mathbb N}$ be some subset of a Hilbert space $H$. If

$$\|f\|^2=\sum|\langle f,e_j\rangle|^2$$

for every $f\in H$, how may I show that

$$\sum\langle f,e_j\rangle e_j$$

converges for every $f\in H$?

Comment: well you need $\|f\|<\infty$, then it is just the triangle inequality.

Comment: @DanielFisher, would you mind to show some more details in the below answer box?

Comment: @DanielFischer, I get stuck at $\|e_k\|^2=\sum_{j\neq k}|\langle e_k,e_j\rangle|^2+\|e_k\|^4$, which implies that $\|e_k\|\leq1$

Comment: @DanielFischer The family isn't necessarily orthogonal, suppose you have some orthonormal basis $(g_j)_j$ then $e_1 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} g_1$, $e_2 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} g_1$, $e_3 = g_2$, $e_4 =g_3$, ... would still satisfy the hypothesis but wouldn't be orthogonal.

Comment: @Demophilus Oops, I got my exponents wrong.

Comment: Please verify my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define $S:H\to H$ by $f\mapsto\sum\langle f,e_j\rangle e_j$. $S$ is well defined since, for every $f\in H$,

$$\begin{align}
\|\sum\langle f,e_j\rangle e_j\|^2&=\sup_{\|g\|=1}|\langle\sum\langle f,e_j\rangle e_j,g\rangle|^2\\
&=\sup_{\|g\|=1}|\sum\langle f,e_j\rangle\langle e_j,g\rangle|^2\\
&\leq\sup_{\|g\|=1}(\sum|\langle f,e_j\rangle|^2)(\sum|\langle e_j,g\rangle|^2)\\
&=\sup_{\|g\|=1}\|f\|^2\|g\|^2\\
&=\|f\|^2.
\end{align}$$

Therefore, if $f\in H$,

$$\begin{align}
\langle Sf,f\rangle&=\langle\sum\langle f,e_j\rangle e_j,f\rangle\\
&=\sum\langle f,e_j\rangle\langle e_j,f\rangle\\
&=\sum\langle f,e_j\rangle\overline{\langle f,e_j\rangle}\\
&=\sum|\langle f,e_j\rangle|^2\\
&=\|f\|^2\\
&=\langle f,f\rangle.
\end{align}$$

This implies that $Sf=f$ for every $f\in H$.

Comment: $\left<Sf,f\right>=\left<f,f\right>$ will imply $Sf=f$?